# Stripe extension fails with a new account (civi 4.7.20)

Tags: stripe

I have been using Stripe extension (4.7.1) successfully, on several accounts, for several months (using webform integration).

I have just upgraded civi to 4.7.20 (/Drupal 7.56), and everything still works fine.

But now :

I have just openned a new Stripe account, created a pertaining Payment Processor, Contribution Page, and a webform to manage Contributions (as I previously did for previous accounts).

- When I make a contribution using this webform, my payment goes to an
  other Stripe account.
- When I make a contribution simply using the
  Contribution Page
  (https://mysite.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=xx), I get
  the following message : "Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this
  message to the site administrator."

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just upgraded Stripe Extension to 4.7.dev, which solved the second issue (stripe.js token not passed).

I close this post and open a new one to be more precise concerning the first issue (payment goes to an other account) : see :
 [Webform Contribution Payment is paid to a wrong Account](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/webform-contribution-payment-is-paid-to-a-wrong-account)